# SSRS using top(@parameter) with report parameters results in an "invalid value"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

This is on SQL Server 2016 and SSRS 2016.

I have a dataset where I am starting by creating a list of dates using a query similar to this:

```
declare @StartDate date = '2018-07-01';
declare @EndDate date = '2018-09-30';

if object_id('tempdb..#TempTable') is not null drop table #TempTable;

select top(datediff(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
    identity(int, 0, 1) as n
into
    #TempTable
from
    sys.all_columns
```

This works fine when I was explicitly declare the start and end dates in the dataset query. I would like to have the start and end dates be report parameters, so I removed the declarations and set up the report parameters for a Start Date (named ReportParamStartDate) and an End Date (named ReportParamEndDate), both set as Dates, not null, and I gave them default values of '2018-07-01' and '2018-09-30' respectively. The parameters themselves seem fine, I am able to grab them using a simple `select @ReportParamStartDate` query and display them on the report. However, when I modify my query to the following I get an error:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#TempTable') is not null drop table #TempTable;

select top(datediff(d, @ReportParamStartDate, @ReportParamEndDate) + 1)
    identity(int, 0, 1) as n
into
    #TempTable
from
    sys.all_columns
```

The error I get is:

> A TOP or FETCH clause contains an invalid value.

I tried going into the Parameters properties for the dataset, and I set `@StartDate` = `[@ReportParamStartDate]`, as well as the end date, and modified my query again to use `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`. But this results in the same error.

I thought maybe I could get around this by adding another dataset parameter which equals the datediff that I am calculating. I created a dataset parameter named `@DateDiffParam` and set it equal to `=DateDiff("d", Parameters!ReportParamStartDate.Value, Parameters!ReportParamEndDate.Value) + 1`, and then modified my query to the following:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#TempTable') is not null drop table #TempTable;

select top(@DateDiffParam)
    identity(int, 0, 1) as n
into
    #TempTable
from
    sys.all_columns
```

This now gives me the following error:

> The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer.

So I tried adding `CInt` to the expression, but that resulted in the same error. I searched a bit and found someone fixed this error by doing `select top (1 * @parameter)`, but adding the `1 *` to my query results in the original error.

If I calculate the datediff as a report parameter (set as an Integer) and use that in the query, that also results in the second error, and trying the `1 * @parameter` solution for this method also reverts back to the original error.

At this point, the only solution that I can think of is to Filter the dataset. But I would like to avoid that if possible, so I am hoping there is something I am missing with regards to getting the `top()` clause working with report parameters.

Comment: Make sure that your repoirt parameters are of type date/time.

Comment: Does the error only occur in design mode? If so then when you send the command to sql-server to parse and make sense of the result set, I bet it is not able to parse. Try changing the value to a constant integer and refresh the fields, however, if the error is at runtime then ignore this comment.

Comment: Data types are both date/time for those report parameters. I am able to use them as I normally would in other queries, but for some reason they don't seem to be playing nice with `top`.

I only noticed it in design mode so far, but changing to `top(1)`, refreshing fields, changing back, and then running the report results in an error during report processing.

Comment: I was able to replicate your error but when I changed the @DateDiffParam to **integer**, it worked correctly in the Preview. I also got the `top(datediff(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)` to work as well without issues. Sometimes starting from scratch works :( .

Comment: @HannoverFist Interesting. Your DateDiffParam worked as a report parameter? I have not been able to get a report parameter working in the top clause no matter what I do. Even creating a brand new blank report, setting a report parameter as an Integer and setting the default value and only available value to 1, I still get the error stating that it must be an integer. Would you possibly be able to upload the .rdl with a query that works on your end? If not, no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a quick report that used both the dates and the datediff integer for parameters and got both to work using your same query. I did get the same error when the parameter was text but when I changed it to integer, it worked.

Here's the report code to check out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="ODS">
      <DataSourceReference>KHSSQLODSPRD</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>dec28a21-e8a3-4a0c-ac30-1d88f88d8d0f</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>ODS</DataSourceName>
        <QueryParameters>
          <QueryParameter Name="@ReportParamStartDate">
            <Value>=Parameters!ReportParamStartDate.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
          <QueryParameter Name="@ReportParamEndDate">
            <Value>=Parameters!ReportParamEndDate.Value</Value>
          </QueryParameter>
        </QueryParameters>
        <CommandText>select top(datediff(d, @ReportParamStartDate, @ReportParamEndDate) + 1)
--top(@datediffParam)
    identity(int, 0, 1) as n
into #TempTable
from sys.all_columns

select * from #TempTable</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="n">
          <DataField>n</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix2">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>1in</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox22">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>n</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                    <Color>DimGray</Color>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style>
                                <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                              </Style>
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox19</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <BackgroundColor>LightGrey</BackgroundColor>
                            <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox40">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>=Fields!n.Value</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontFamily>Calibri</FontFamily>
                                    <Color>DimGray</Color>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style>
                                <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                              </Style>
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox30</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                            </Border>
                            <BackgroundColor>=CODE.AlternateColor("White", "AliceBlue", 1, 0)</BackgroundColor>
                            <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                            <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
            <TablixColumnHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixColumnHierarchy>
            <TablixRowHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember>
                  <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                </TablixMember>
                <TablixMember>
                  <Group Name="Details" />
                </TablixMember>
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixRowHierarchy>
            <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
            <Height>0.5in</Height>
            <Width>1in</Width>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
            </Style>
          </Tablix>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>0.5in</Height>
        <Style />
      </Body>
      <Width>8.5in</Width>
      <Page>
        <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>
        <PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>
        <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="ReportParamStartDate">
      <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>Report Param Start Date</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="ReportParamEndDate">
      <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>2/1/2018 12:00:00 AM</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>Report Param End Date</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="datediffParam">
      <DataType>Integer</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>12</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>datediff Param</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>4</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>2</NumberOfRows>
      <CellDefinitions>
        <CellDefinition>
          <ColumnIndex>0</ColumnIndex>
          <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
          <ParameterName>ReportParamStartDate</ParameterName>
        </CellDefinition>
        <CellDefinition>
          <ColumnIndex>1</ColumnIndex>
          <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
          <ParameterName>ReportParamEndDate</ParameterName>
        </CellDefinition>
        <CellDefinition>
          <ColumnIndex>2</ColumnIndex>
          <RowIndex>0</RowIndex>
          <ParameterName>datediffParam</ParameterName>
        </CellDefinition>
      </CellDefinitions>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <Code>Public bOddRow(10) As Boolean 

Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean, ByVal Type AS INTEGER) As String 

  If Toggle Then bOddRow(Type) = Not bOddRow(Type) 

  If bOddRow(Type) Then 
                Return OddColor 
  Else 
                Return EvenColor 
  End If 

End Function</Code>
  <Language>en-US</Language>
  <ConsumeContainerWhitespace>true</ConsumeContainerWhitespace>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>93b48dbc-8a58-48e4-a4a5-2dcdf6700445</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

Here's the Preview: 
[image: Preview]

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is something with my environment then, because I still get the _"The number of rows provided for a TOP or FETCH clauses row count parameter must be an integer."_ error when I set the query on this report to use the datediffparam (I double checked to make sure it was set to Integer, and casting it in the query results in the original error again).